# ngx-perfect-scrollbar is deprecated

Tags: angular, deprecated, npm-package, ngx-perfect-scrollbar

I found out that ngx-perfect-scrollbar has been deprecated. I found out the npm package health analysis says that this package is safe until now but it is not supported anymore.
link: https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar

so I have searched for alternatives to get a similar package that is well supported and I didn't find anything that could help me.

What are the alternatives that could replace this package?

Comment: have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scrollbar ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The author of that library himself has decided to drop support for it check this message here: https://openbase.com/js/ngx-perfect-scrollbar/versions

[image]

he advices to use [ngx-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scrollbar)

Comment: I didn't see this before. Thank you.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if you find it helpful ?

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I just did it.